# Is it possible to query value of SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME parameter?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, parameter

Can somebody advice whether it is possible to query for current value of SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME parameter in Oracle 11 DB?

Should

```
select * from v$parameter
```

return value of SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME (if it has been configured)?

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this?

Comment: I'm not an admin on Oracle server which run DBs, only have admin rights within DBs - so just wanted to find out whether there is some quick way to check this w/o need to look at server side config file. In particular need to compare this settings for different DBs? Though as I understand it is per connection profile not per DB setting - please correct me if I'm wrong/explain this to me.

Comment: Maybe one external table (with one "long" varchar column) for each server-side configuration file could be very useful to you? Then you could simply `select *` on these tables to "cat" them.

Answer (score 4):

No, it can't be queried. These values are stored in sqlnet.ora on either or both of the client and the server.

In either case, none of the contents of the network configuration files sqlnet.ora, tnsnames.ora, listener.ora etc (eg protocol.ora, snmp.ora, cman.ora) can be queried.

If you really need to read the contents of these files and can't solve this problem in some other way (programatically via some OS level program or even administratively), you could read the file via external tables or via a Java stored procedure.

I would prefer to solve this outside of the database.