# Find active values of SQLNET.ORA parameters on server

Tags: oracle

How can I find the active values of [SQLNET.ORA parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF006) on the server?

I know how to find the SQLNET.ORA file but there's no guarantee the values in that file are actively used.  Parameter changes may require restarting the listener and sometimes even [restarting the database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/54606/3336).  For debugging I want a way to be 100% certain how the parameters are set, without restarting anything.

This is similar to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/54502/3336), but I am looking for *any* method to find the current values.  It doesn't have to be a SQL query.

Here's what I've tried so far that leads me to believe it's impossible:

1. Tracing does not generate that data.
2. There does not appear to be anything in the data dictionary.
3. There's no information in the manual or support.oracle.com.
4. Offered a bounty but no takers. (But I'll offer and award another bounty if anyone can answer this.)

Comment: I don't know. But if one starts a program with TRACE_SQL_SERVER=SUPPORT in sqlnet.ora one can try to find out something  about the sqlnet properties.

Comment: @miracle173 Setting `TRACE_LEVEL_SERVER=support` does take effect right away, but the trace files don't appear to have information about the parameters.

Comment: I dont think there is a way using SQL, excep for wallet location perhaps.

Comment: @Raj It doesn't have to be from SQL.  I'm looking for *any* way to find the current settings.

Comment: I don't know of any way, you can log a SR and ask Oracle support. But I doubt they will tell you. My understanding is these are not persisted but accessed during listener start-up and client authentication.

Comment: @Raj I edited the question to clarify that I'm only interested in the server-side SQLNET.ORA parameters.

Comment: I understand, still my guess is those are only read at listener start-up/reload and during client session authentication. Why? because lsof command doesn't show this file is being used by any process. These parameters are not exposed as environment variables for the process (I checked that).

Comment: @Raj: as far a I know the sqlnet.ora is read by a new shadow process. So if you enable server side sqlnet tracing this will be enabled for all sessions that are created after you changed the sqlnet.ora until these processes end, even if you disable sqlnet tracing in the sqlnet.ora file after a while.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters set in the sqlnet.ora file are not exposed in any data dictionary table.  You can't write a SQL query to find them.

Source:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2550107?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: A query would be nice but I am explicitly looking for *any* method.  However, the methods listed in that source will not work.  Just reading the sqlnet.ora file is not sufficient for multiple reasons.